# Некорректно отрабатывает тест

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Есть два Entity, первая BaseModel, который содержит id и от него наследуются другие Entity.

```
 @Entity
 abstract class BaseModel {

 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 @Getter
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private long id;

 public BaseModel(long id) {
    this.id = id;
 }

 protected BaseModel() {
    }
}
```

Вторая Entity, Pupil.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pupil")
public final class Pupil extends BaseModel {

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "pupilID")
private PupilInClassRoom pupilInClassRoom;

@Column(nullable = false)
@Getter
@Setter
private String name;

@Getter
@Setter
@Column(nullable = false)
private String surname;

public Pupil(long id,String name, String surname) {
    super(id);
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}

public Pupil() {
  }
}
```

Делаю тест на добавление в таблицу.

```
@Rollback(value = false)
public Pupil contextLoads() {
    Pupil pupil1 = new Pupil();
    pupil1.setName("Hello");
    pupil1.setSurname("hello");
    return pupilRepository.save(pupil1);

}

@Test
public void testCount() {
    Pupil pupil = contextLoads();
    System.out.println(pupil);
}
```

Стартую тест и он мне говорит, что поле DISCIPLINE, которые есть в другой Entity(Teacher) не может быть NULL, что верно, но какое отношение это имеет к добавлению Pupil.

```
NULL not allowed for column "DISCIPLINE"; SQL statement:
insert into base_model (name, pupilid, surname, dtype, id) values (?, ?, ?, 'Pupil', ?) [23502-200]
```

Другой вариант теста

```
@Before("contextLoads()")
@Rollback(value = false)
public void contextLoads() {
    Pupil pupil1 = new Pupil();
    pupil1.setName("Hello");
    pupil1.setSurname("hello");
    pupilRepository.save(pupil1);

}

@Test
public void testCount() {
    System.out.println(pupilRepository.findAll());
}
```

В данном случае в консоль падает

```
[]
```

Хотя должен вывести одного Pupil

Если для филда discipline в Entity Teacher сделать @Column(nullable = true)
то все отрабатывает корректно.
В консоль падает

```
com.SchoolJournal.SpringHibernate.model.Pupil@2b625e82
```

Тест на выборку данных:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT p.id, p.name, p.surname FROM pupil as p " +
"INNER JOIN pupil_in_class_room as in ON p.id = in.pupilID " +
"INNER JOIN teacher as t ON t.id = in.teacherID " +
        "WHERE t.name(:name)")
List<Pupil> findPupilByTeacher(@Param("name") String name);
```

Ошибка

```
Schema "T" not found; SQL statement:
```

Comment: `insert into base_model` не в ту таблицу делает insert?

Comment: @tym32167 да я вот понять не могу) я описал выше варианты, которые пробовал, но мне не нравится, то что филд мне приходится nullable = true.
Сам репо выглядит так: public interface PupilRepository extends CrudRepository<Pupil,Long>

Comment: @tym32167 Я сейчас проверил, он такую штуку выбрасывает на все Entity, только поля разные: NULL not allowed for column "NAME"; SQL statement:
insert into base_model (dtype, id) values ('PupilInClassRoom', ?) [23502-200]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это [нормальное и ожидаемое](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html)  поведение, когда для хранения иерархии объектов используется одна таблица (`Table per class hierarchy`):

> There is a limitation of this mapping strategy: columns declared by the subclasses, such as CCTYPE, cannot have NOT NULL constraints.

В этом случае в одной таблице хранятся поля всех наследников (в данном случае класса `BaseModel`). Там хранятся как поля базового класса, так и поля классов из иерархии. Для того, чтоб понимать, какого именно типа объект хранится в записи используется специальное поле - дискриминатор (в вашем случае `dtype`). И поля в таком случае не могут иметь ограничения `not null`, т.к. значения в колонках для полей объекта одного подкласса, скажем поле `discipline` из `Teacher`) будут всегда пустыми в записях для другого подкласса, скажем `Pupil`.

Если это ограничение вам не подходит, то нужно переключиться на другую стратегию хранения иерархии: `table per class` или `joined table`.

В первом случае добавьте `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` к базовому классу.

Во втором случае добавьте `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` к базовому классу.

Comment: Спасибо) если при тесте я использую свой @Query(отредактировал топик), который осуществляет выборку данных из разных таблиц, он пишет Schema "T" not found, это тоже зависит от стратегии?

Comment: Это вообще никак не связанная проблема. У вас синтаксическая ошибка в SQL-запросе, скорее всего вы хотели написать `t.name = :name`. Не нужно в один вопрос все проблемы складировать :)